# Young's Convolution Inequality for Vector Functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

I would like to apply [Young's Convolution Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) to the following functions:

$f,g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $ g: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. That is, $f(x)$ is an $N$-vector, whilst $g(x)$ is a scalar, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

My question is whether or not we can still apply Young's Inequality in this case. Is the convolution still well defined? I think the following definition is intuitive:

$ (f \ast g)(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} f(x-y)g(y) \text{d}y =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} [f_{1}(x-y)g(y), ... ,f_{N}(x-y)g(y) ] \text{d}y$

The desired inequality is of course:

$ ||f \ast g||_{L^1} \leq ||f||_{L^1}||g||_{L^1} $

Using this definition, I followed the proof of Young's Inequality found in Haim Brezis's Functional Analysis textbook, and the proof doesn't seem to change whatsoever.

Comment: $f$ can bee seen as $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_N)$ and usual properties apply to $f_i * g$. You only need to define what you mean by $\|f\|_{L^1}$ when $f$ output is in $\mathbb{R}^N$, if it is equal to $\sum \|f_i\|_{L^1}$ then it works.

Comment: I was thinking $||f|| = \int |f| \text{d}x = \int \sqrt{|f_1|^2 + ... + |f_N|^2} \text{d}x$. Is this not an acceptable definition of $L^1$ norm when $f$ outputs in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$?

Comment: I am not aware of any standard definition of $L^p$ spaces for vector valued functions (it must have already been considered though). However, taking your definition leads to prove : $\|h*g^*\|_{L^1} \le \|h\|_{L^1}\|g^*\|_{L^1}$ with $h = \sqrt{|f_1|^2 + ... + |f_N|^2}$ and $g^* = |g|$, which is true by Young's Inequality.

Comment: @Nicomezi - Brilliant. That is just what I was thinking. Thanks for confirming